# Build failure while setting up Maven project

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka

I'm learning Kafka from the official documentation (https://kafka.apache.org/25/documentation/streams/tutorial) and the tutorial asks me to create a Maven project but when I run this command

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.kafka \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=streams-quickstart-java \
    -DarchetypeVersion=2.5.0 \
    -DgroupId=streams.examples \
    -DartifactId=streams.examples \
    -Dversion=0.1 \
    -Dpackage=myapps
```

I get the following error:

`org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory`

I'm new to Kafka and Maven and having trouble debugging this. I have tried adding quotes for every parameter, but it didn't help. I'm using Windows 10. Any idea what the problem might be? Thanks!

Comment: why don't you write mvn archetype:generate? actual command is mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.kafka \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=streams-quickstart-java \
    -DarchetypeVersion=2.5.0 \
    -DgroupId=streams.examples \
    -DartifactId=streams.examples \
    -Dversion=0.1 \
    -Dpackage=myapps

Comment: are you on windows?

Comment: I did, sorry I didn't copy the entire command.

Comment: @tashkhisi yes, I am

Comment: please delete \ at the end of line and make it in one line, all your command should be in on line without \

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\ character in linux system specify that the command will continue in next line but it doesn't work in winsows just ommit \ for all lines and make it one line command

Answer (score 0):

Update: As @tashkhisi pointed out, removing the \ at the end of the lines solved the problem.